# Почему выдаёт ошибку при инициализации потока?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Controller());
            while (true)
            {
                thread1.Start();
                //Thread thread = new Thread(() => Ball());
                for (int i = 1; i < map.GetLength(0) - 1; ++i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); ++j)
                    {
                        Console.Write(map[i, j]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                try
                {
                    map[cordsPlayer[0], 0] = '#';
                    map[cordsPlayer[1], 0] = '#';
                    map[cordsPlayer[2], 0] = '#';
                }
                catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //thread.Join();
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                Console.Clear();
            }
            thread1.Join();
```

Привет, короче проблема в том, что при инициализации потока в не цикла выдаёт ошибкую *Unhandled exception. System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart.*.
Можно ли как-то оставить инициализацию за циклов и исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Controller());
        while (true)
        {
            thread1.Start();
            // ...
```

Зачем вы запускаете тред каждую итерацию цикла? Вы не можете несколько раз запустить один и тот же тред. Что с этим делать - зависит от того, какое поведение вы хотите от треда.

Например, вы хотите запустить тред один раз и пусть работает пока вы что-то делаете в цикле:

```
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Controller());
        thread1.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            // ...
        }
        thread1.Join();
```

Или вы хотите, чтобы отдельным запуском треда сопровождалась каждая итерация цикла:

```
        while (true)
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Controller());
            thread1.Start();
            // ...
            thread1.Join();
        }
```